# A convex spherical refracting surface

Tags: physics

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> A convex spherical refracting surface with a radius of 0.6 m separates
> a medium whose index of refraction is 1.5 from another whose index of
> refraction is 2.0. An object is placed in the first medium 1.0 m from
> the surface. Determine the focal distances of the object and image,
> the position of the image, and the magnification of the image.

Here is my attempt:

> The focal length of a lens or a refracting surface can be determined
> using the lens formula:
>
> $1/f = (n_2 - n_1)(1 / R_1 - 1 / R_2)$
>
> Since we have a single convex spherical refracting surface, we can
> assume the other surface has an infinite radius of curvature, so the
> lens formula simplifies to:
>
> $1/f = (n_2 - n_1) \cdot (1 / R_1)$
>
> Substituting the given values:
>
> $1/f = (2.0 - 1.5) \cdot (1 / 0.6)$
>
> Solving for $f$:
>
> $1/f = 0.5 \cdot (5 / 3)$
>
> Therefore, $f = 1.2 \, \text{m}$

But I should obtain that it is 1.8m. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the textbook of the question, please?

Comment: You can't apply the lens formula. That one assumes that the light moves from $n_1$ to $n_2$ **and back** to $n_1$.

Comment: @Andrei Could you please explain how I can approche this problem then?

Answer (score 0):

Any introductory optics book contain a chapter about refraction from spherical surfaces. For example, you can take a look at [this](https://phys.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD%3A_Physics_9B__Waves_Sound_Optics_Thermodynamics_and_Fluids/04%3A_Geometrical_Optics/4.04%3A_Spherical_Refractors). The formula you want to use is $$\frac{n_1}{d_1}+\frac{n_2}{d_2}=\frac{n_2-n_1}R$$
Notice that you have different focal lengths on the two sides of the surface. If the object is at infinity, $d_1=\infty$, so the image is in the focal point $f_2$:
$$f_2=R\frac{n_2}{n_2-n_1}=2.4m$$
If you want the image to be at infinity, $d_2=\infty$, you put the object at $f_1$:
$$f_1=R\frac{n_1}{n_2-n_1}=1.8m$$